# What happened to the money in Blackhat?

Tags: plot-explanation, blackhat

I'm a little late here, I didn't see *Blackhat* in theatres.

Why did he only have about 50 million dollars in the bank at the end?

He took 78 million dollars from that bad guy!

They should have explained that, unless I missed something.

I assume he somehow donated 28 million dollars to a relief fund (whitehat style), or he spent it on 365 new Corvettes so he could drive one for every day of the year.

Or he sent it to his girlfriend's remaining family.

Comment: Could it just be a $ to € conversion fail? http://i.stack.imgur.com/imFcg.png.  by the directors? That being said, the Euro amount works out to precisely (almost to the dollar) $50M...

Comment: I noticed how it was almost exactly 50 million with the conversion, which could kind of explain how he decided to keep 50 and the rest go to something else maybe. Could be a scene that explained it that was cut or something. I can't say for sure, it's bugging me though. That money was a very important part of the movie, and that's a lot of dough to be missing!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, he took **74 million dollars** from the Blackhat, not 78. The remaining difference is likely due to a little detail you missed. The bank account at the end doesn't show 50 million dollars, but **50 million (or rather ~47 million) euro** (screenshot as edited and provided by Richard in a comment):

[image]

If we look at the time of the movie's creation, [which was around 2013](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackhat_%28film%29#Production) and the dollar-euro exchange rates in that year (as provided by the [European Central Bank](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/exchange/eurofxref/html/eurofxref-graph-usd.en.html)), they were around a rather stable ~1.35 during that period:

[image]

If we consider additional factors, like a more liberal approximation of that rate by the filmmakers, the bank not offering the most favourable exchange rate, or Hathaway already having spent quite a bit for travel expenses and the like, then **this amount isn't that unrealistic in the scenario of the film**.